# How to pass data from one actionmethod to another in ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm wondering how I should do this: I get the ID of an item by using the `asp-route-id="@item.ID"` method.

```
<a asp-controller="Outfit" asp-action="OutfitRatingOpslaan" 
   asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="btn btn-primary">Beoordelen</a>
```

This ID needs to be remembered for the view:

```
public IActionResult OutfitRatingOpslaan(item.ID)
{
    Object obj = Container.GetObject(item.ID)       
}
```

So the `ID` of that object, needs to be combined with the value i get after pressing on a submit button in the `OutfitRatingOpslaan(Item.ID)` view.

I have added a picture on how the view looks like and where the user can enter a value.

[image]

This new value + the `ID` of the object need to be combined and stored inside database.

So the end result should look something like this:

```
public IActionResult OutfitRatingSave()
{
    Rating rating = ratingContainer.AddRating(item.ID, Value);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas ? ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods can achieve it.

**First method,** You can use:

```
return RedirectToAction("action", "controller", new { id = item.ID});
```

Then in target action, Just use :

```
public IActionResult OutfitRatingSave(int id)
{
    Rating rating = ratingContainer.AddRating(id, Value);
}
```

**Second method**, You can use `TempData["xx"]` to pass data between actions, refer to below code:

```
public IActionResult OutfitRatingOpslaan(item.ID)
{
    TempData["id"] = item.ID
    Object obj = Container.GetObject(item.ID)       
}

public IActionResult OutfitRatingSave()
{
    int id = (int)TempData["id"];
    Rating rating = ratingContainer.AddRating(id, Value);
}
```